# Pass a variable value from one php page to another

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

I'm trying to send the value of this php get_field variable from a wordpress Archive page.

`get_field('supplier_email_address', 'product_brand_' . $term->term_id );`

to another sendmessage.php page which is never accessed other than with the of JS to send a form. The variable I need filled is called:

`$sendto="value";`

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Apparently this requires more information.

Comment: Please make sure you include into your QUESTION the bugs you are having and the related code you TRIED. StackOverflow is'nt here to do your homework for you, will gladly help anyone with a bug or a question.

Comment: information added. No other code tried. I'm not asking for you to do my homework...I'm here because I have a code problem.

Comment: Maybe you could go do some research on google then try something THEN if it dont work you could edit your answer with the code you tried and than we wont have to do your work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use session variables.

First of all every page you want to use sessions on needs to have the function session_start(); declared at the top of every page. You then can use the session superglobal to store things.

```
Pg1.php:
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['variable_name'] = 'string';
    ?>

Pg2.php:
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['variable_name'];
    ?>
Pg2.php will show: some string
```

Comment: See comments on @ChunkyBaconPlz answer for more info

Comment: Nambi, that worked absolutely perfectly! I had to place session_start(); literally at the very top of the page though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either `POST` your value so your second page can retrieve it in the `$_POST` array, or include it in the URL path so your second page can `$_GET` it.

Without more info, we can't really help you any more than that.

Comment: Could also use $_SESSION['']

Comment: @Sebastien is it really good practice to be passing arbitrary variables with $_SESSION? I do it for things that are site-wide like user IDs and the like, but I'm curious as to what the implications are when doing it for things you could be POSTing instead.

Comment: its not always good practice like you mentionned but I just wanted to provide the more complete information possible so Mike Jackson could himself evaluate what is the best option for his project or this part of code.

Comment: @Sebastien Fair enough, I was just genuinely curious.

Comment: You are perfectly right here, its just that with the code provided and the fact that he did'nt even try anything there might be more to the question then what we see.

Comment: I think its always better to have more info than not enought!